# Get list of feature types from WFS without full GetCapabilities document

Tags: geoserver, wfs, getcapabilities

Is there a way to get the names of all the feature types on a WFS server, other than just calling `GetCapabilities`? On the server I'm interested in (GeoServer, supports WFS 1.1.0), that's a 50MB XML file.

Answer (score 2):

I don't suppose it's your server, hey?

Removing the unnecessary CRSs from GeoServer can make the XML significantly smaller...

The only way I know of to get less info is to limit it to a single workspace, so something like `geoserver/workspacename/ows?service=WFS&request=GetCapabilities`. Can you share the URL for the service?

As mentioned by @gis-haderslev, you can also make a `DescribeFeatureType` request, without specifying the typename and you will get all the feature types of the service

> geoserver/workspacename/ows?service=WFS&request=DescribeFeatureType&version=1.1.0&

But this is meant to give more detail than the GetCapabilities response and typically asking for all the feature types this way is going to be more verbose.

Answer (score -1):

geoserver/workspacename/ows?service=WFS&**request=DescribeFeatureType**

Comment: request requires a version parameter to be valid

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/178225)

Comment: @J.Monticolo strictly it does attempt to provide an answer to `Is there a way to get the names of all the feature types on a WFS server, other than just calling GetCapabilities?`  you can do it with a DescribeFeatureType.  As a one line answer though it's a bit lacking in detail, and the syntax is wrong but...

Comment: But a single ligne of code, non formated post without a minimum of context, explanation and link to a documentation, etc. It's for me for a first answer a lazy answer. I provide more contextual answer as comments ...